# Remove a child from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have this array:

```
$queue = array("orange", "banana", 'apple', 'watermelon');
```

If I want to remove any of them,for example I want to remove banana, how to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of several of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+delete+from+array

Comment: Sory, I am new here. Please delete if its unnecessary. My bad. Sorry!!

Comment: That's ok.  But for next time, make sure to do a little bit of due diligence and search for your question before you create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (in_array('banana', $array)) 
{
    unset($array[array_search('banana', $array)]);
}
```

Comment: It should be `unset($array[array_search('banana', $array)]);` on line 3

Comment: Oops. Typed too fast. Nice catch. +1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for that element and remove it using the key:

```
$pos = array_search('banana', $array);
if ($pos !== false) {
    unset($array[$pos]);
}
```

If the array can contain the value more than once, you should use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) instead:

```
foreach (array_keys($array, 'banana') as $key) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$array = array_filter($array, create_function('$v', 'return $v != \'value to remove\';'));
```

Comment: As of PHP 5.3 you don't need to use create_function, you can just write an anonymous one inline.<br>`function($v) { return $v != 'value to remove'; }`